# How can i upload an image if i'm navigating to a different component

Tags: react-native, redux

I am working on a react native application where i an upload image button in the Upload screen and during the upload process if i navigate back to the previous screen the upload process is stopped but i would want to upload the image in background of the app.

I am sure where to start trying this.

how will i approach this problem. Is there is any package i could use, i am even persisting data in redux store after the image is uploaded so is there a way i can use redux to upload the image.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing would be.

You can show uploading indicator while uploading and then return promise to navigate whatever the page you want.